# Implementing DFS in Ruby

Tags: ruby, depth-first-search

I am trying to figure out how to make Water Bucket problem solver, using Depth First Search.
And I am running into problem where i somehow get states that can not exits.
Right now implementing only processes FILL and EMPTY

```
Example:
  2 jugs, 3l, 4l, I need 4
input :> 2,3,4,4
Output :> inf. loop of [[3,3],[3.3]]
```

I am using Node Class

```
class Node
 attr_reader :parent, :state, :childrens

 def initialize(parent, state, childrens)
   @parent = parent
   @state = state
   @childrens = childrens
 end

end
```

And a main class that should implement DFS

```rb
require_relative 'node'

$solutions = Array.new

def DFS(node, bag, target)

  puts "Starting Function"
  node.state.each do |s|
    s.size.times do |b|


=begin
     FILL FUNCTION
=end

      # Loome uue seisu
      n_state = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(s))
      n_state[b][1] = n_state[b][0]
      n_state = [n_state]
      # Kontrollime, kas on juba olnud
      if bag.has_key?(n_state)
       return bag
      end

      # Kontrollime, kas on lahendus
      solution = n_state.select{|k| k.any?{|v| v[1] == target}}[0]

      if solution
        $solutions.push(n_state)
        return bag
      end


      bag[node.state] = n_state.to_s + " FILL "
      child = Node.new(node, n_state, nil)
      puts child.state.to_s + " : " + bag.to_s
      bag = DFS(child, bag, target)

=begin
     EMPTY FUNCTION
=end

  # Loome uue seisu
  kann = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(s))
  kann[b][1] = 0
  n_state = [n_state]
  # Kontrollime, kas on juba olnud
  if bag.has_key?(n_state)
    return bag
  end

  # Kontrollime, kas on lahendus
  solution = n_state.select{|k| k.any?{|v| v[1] == target}}[0]

  if solution
    $solutions.push(n_state)
    return bag
  end


  bag[node.state] = n_state.to_s + " Empty "
  child = Node.new(node, n_state, nil)
  puts child.state.to_s + " : " + bag.to_s
  DFS(child, bag, target)



end
end



end

=begin
Sisendi Muster järgimne :
"a , a * [x] , d" ,
kus a on veekannude arv,
 a*[x] on veekannued mahud
  ja d on soovitud lõpptulemus
Näide:
2 , 3 , 4 , 2
Mul on 2 veekannu 3l ja 4l. Tulemuseks tahan saada 2l.
=end

# Küsime sisendi

input = gets.split(/,/).map{|p| p.to_i} # Saame sisendi lõigume tükkideks "," järgi ja muudame kõik osad intideks (to_int)

# Määrame ära keskkonna.

count = input.shift # saame koguse
start = (1..count).map{[input.shift, 0]} # saame iga veekannu mahu
target= input.shift # viimane element on meie soovitud tulemus

step = 0
states = {start => ""} # Hashmap, kus start on võti ja "" väärtus.

 current = states.keys
start_node = Node.new(nil, current, nil)
 states = {start => ""}

puts "GIVING STATE : " + current.to_s
DFS(start_node, states, target)
puts "SOLUTIONS FOUND :"
puts $solutions.to_s
```

Comment: I have a solution that uses breadth first search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out what was wrong, specially with the comments in a language I don't understand, so I did it from scratch.
Some of the key aspects are:

- Separation of the code that generates a new state from the code that handles which states were tried already. This makes it a lot easier to make sure the states you generate are valid.
- I didn't use the concept of nodes, because they're not needed in this case.
- Each state is represented by an array with the values of the quantity in each bucket;
- DFS returns an array of states that take you from the goal to the start. You can change the ordering if you want.

> ```
> def drop_onto(state, from_max, to_max, from, to)
>   
>   if (state[from] == 0 || state[to] == to_max)    #From is empty or To is full
>       return state        
>   end
>   
>   new_state = state.dup
>   missing_to = to_max - state[to]
>   if state[from] > missing_to then    #Fill to
>       new_state[from] -= missing_to
>       new_state[to] += missing_to
>   else                                #Empty from
>       new_state[to] += new_state[from]
>       new_state[from] = 0
>   end
>   
>   return new_state
> end
>
>
> def DFS(buckets, visited, state, goal)
>   
>   return false if visited[state]
>   return [[state]] if state == goal   #We reached our goal!
>   visited[state] = true
>
>   state.each_with_index do |from_quantity, from|
>       state.each_with_index do |to_quantity, to|
>           next if from == to  # Don't drop onto itself
>           
>           new_state = drop_onto state, buckets[from], buckets[to], from, to
>           try_dfs = DFS buckets, visited, new_state, goal
>           return try_dfs.push state if try_dfs    #In case we found something, add state to the list
>           
>       end
>   end
>   
>   return false
> end
>
> buckets = [3, 5, 8]
> visited = Hash.new
> start = [0, 0, 8]
> goal = [0, 4, 4]
> print DFS buckets, visited, start, goal
> ```